# rails - attach xls file to email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, spreadsheet, xls

I created a code which generate xls file, then i pass it to the Mailer to send it as an attachment. But , I keep getting the same errors again and again :

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Spreadsheet::Workbook into String
```

Or

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for #<Spreadsheet::Workbook:0x007fe937e4fe80>
```

My code is :

```
def xls_mailer (data)
attachments['HelloWorld.xlsx'] = data
mail(subject: "Hi", to: @gmail.email)
end
```

***data - is the xls file which I;m passing to this Method.

Thank you guys ahead,

Comment: what gem do you use for generating `xlsx`?

Comment: @devanand I'm using : 'spreadsheet', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
and 'to_spreadsheet'

Comment: is `data` a string? maybe not. then you'll get the `length` error. debug what kind of data `data` is.

Comment: @devanand what you mean "debug what kind of data is"? 
I dont understand you ...

Comment: What datatype is the parameter `data`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay Guys, I found out the answer. 
The code should be like this :

```
 spreadsheet_file = StringIO.new
 data.write(spreadsheet_file)
 attachments['HelloWorld.xls'] = spreadsheet_file.read
```

Answer (score 1):

Action Mailer expects you to pass it a [`File`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html)-like object as an attachment, but your code's passing it the spreadsheet data directly. Fortunately, Ruby has a class called [`StringIO`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) that we can use to convert our spreadsheet into something that acts like a `File`:

```
def xls_mailer (spreadsheet)
  spreadsheet_file = StringIO.new
  spreadsheet.write(spreadsheet_file)
  attachments['HelloWorld.xls'] = spreadsheet_file
  mail(subject: "Hi", to: @gmail.email)
end
```

Comment: thank you for the code, I've tried it. But, when I got the mail and try to open the xls file, it's wrote : 
"The file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Comment: That seems to be a [semi-common problem](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/issues?utf8=✓&q=is%3Aissue+corrupt) with the spreadsheet gem. Are you trying to modify a spreadsheet that was originally created by Excel on a Mac? Apparently [that's not really supported](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/issues/162#issuecomment-169043728)

Comment: Correct. That's exactly what I'm doing... 
The only answer for that case is to upload the file to my server and then use the path of it to the attachment file.. true?

Comment: No, that won't make a difference. You'll have to create your source spreadsheet with some other program – either Excel on Windows, or through LibreOffice on a Mac.

Comment: I have a Mac but I create the xls file with Excel that I have on it. 
But it still not work ..

Comment: Correct, that won't work. The author of the `spreadsheet` gem [says that Excel on a Mac generates files that don't work with the gem](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/issues/162#issuecomment-169043728). You should make your initial file using Excel on Windows, or using [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org) instead.

Comment: I tried now to use OpenOffice, download it, and changed the prefix of the file to ".ods". But I still getting an empty file .... :(((((

Comment: You should use OpenOffice to save an Excel spreadsheet, so it shouldn't have an 'ods' extension. If it still doesn't work, then you may have a bug elsewhere in your code, and you should post a new question on StackOverflow (as it's not related to attaching files to an email).

Answer (score 1):

The below chunk of code works like a charm. I have tried this, used in a working application.

```
def send_excel_report(file_name, emails, subject, email_content, file_path, bcc_emails = [])

    attachments["#{file_name}.xls"] = File.read(file_path)

    mail(to: emails, subject: subject, from: "my_email@gmail.com", bcc: bcc_emails) do |format|
      format.html { render :partial => "users/mail_body"}
    end
  end
```

FYI: I have used spreadsheet gem to create the excel